# OpenCv Get edge distance to circle center

Tags: opencv, python

A bit off an intro, i need to make a visual aid to align sheets against fixed points.
My setup has 3 points, a sheetmetal plate needs to be positioned against these points using a forklift.
Its a gentle task, we cant use brut force to align the sheet, so i want to install camera's to help them align there sheetmetal plate.

Code so far:

```
import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
val = 50

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
       
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
    gray = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)

    rows = gray.shape[0]
    circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 8,
                           param1=100, param2=30,
                           minRadius=1, maxRadius=30)

    edges = cv.Canny(gray,val,val*3,apertureSize = 3)
    lines = cv.HoughLines(edges,1.2,np.pi/180,200)

    font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    color = (255, 255, 255)
    thickness = 2
    index = 1
    
    if len(circles[0]) > 2 :
    
        circles = np.uint16(np.floor(circles))           
        circles2=sorted(circles[0],key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=False)  
    
        print (circles2)
            
        for i in circles2:
            center = (i[0], i[1])
            cv.circle(frame, center, 1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
        
            text = str(index)  +' ' +  str(i[0]) +' ' +  str(i[1])
            cv.putText(frame, text, center, font, 1, color, thickness, cv.LINE_AA)
        
        index += 1
        
    cv.imshow("detected circles", frame)
    cv.imshow("detected edges", edges)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Output of the code]

So the points are found, somehow i need to find the first 255 value in edges right 'above' the 2nd and 3th point, and the last 255 value next to the first point
i'm struggling too slice? the array, find the value 255, returns its index, so i can calculate the distance between point and plate.

any ideas on how to get the distance between?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There, now you have enough rep to post images, so feel free to [edit] the question and add them.

Comment: Is the sheet always on the right of the 1st and on top of the 2nd/3rd point? If so then you might want to get the center of points (use find contours and centroid) and traverse right to get the second 255 "spike" and similarly for 2nd and 3rd point and traverse up for second 255 spike while counting the number of pixels. If the sheet is tilted then get the tilt angle and traverse with that angle.

Comment: Could you help me how to find that? Np.where? Slice or similar the edges array?  So i have the center XY of the circles, i could use this as the indexes for the edges picture on the right. But working with mutli dimensions array's is new to me, and looping in python is slow so i've been told. Right of the first circle and always on top off the second and third circle, always.

Comment: if you can get your sheet as a contour using findContours, then you can use cv2.pointPolygonTest with measureDist=True to give you the shortest distance to the sheet. do that for the 3 points, but it wont give you the "angle", only the distance but i guess with the 3 points you can figure it out
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d48/tutorial_point_polygon_test.html

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

the code:

```
import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
val = 50
singleprint = 0
# Dots per millimeter
dpmm = 2 

def distance(circle):
    # Calculating the distance np.where(array[row, column])
    p = 0
    if axis == 1:
        p = np.where(edges[:,circle[0]] == 255)[0][0]
        return (circle[1] - p - circle[2])/dpmm
    else:
        p = np.where(edges[circle[1],:] == 255)[0][-1]
        return (p - circle[0] - circle[2])/dpmm

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
           
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
    gray = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)

    rows = gray.shape[0]
    circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 8,
                           param1=100, param2=30,
                           minRadius=1, maxRadius=30)

    edges = cv.Canny(gray,val,val*3,apertureSize = 3)
    lines = cv.HoughLines(edges,1.2,np.pi/180,200)

    # Text property's
    font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    color = (255, 255, 255)
    thickness = 2  

    index = 1
    axis = 0

    if len(circles[0]) > 2 :
    
        circles = np.uint16(np.floor(circles))           
        circles2=sorted(circles[0],key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=False)  
                 
        for i in circles2:
            center = (i[0], i[1])
        
            cv.circle(frame, center, 1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
        
            text = str(distance(i))
            cv.putText(frame, text, center, font, 1, color, thickness, cv.LINE_AA)
        
            index += 1
            axis = 1
     
    cv.imshow("detected circles", frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]
[image]

Key was learning to use Numpy in a specific row or column

```
np.where(edges[:,circle[0]] == 255)[0][0]
```

resource: https://youtu.be/GB9ByFAIAH4?t=1103

Hope this helps others.
Thanks all